# 1 workspace is equal to 1 project on cloud 9 ide?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm reading the prices page https://c9.io/web/site/pricing and see that all the plans say "premium workspace" but do not understand that it's a "premium workspace", a workspace equals a project? or within a workspace you can have many projects?

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In c9 a Workspace means a Virtual Machine.

2 things you can do:

- You can, of course, clone an  entire git project as a workspace.
- Inside any workspace you can clone as many git projects you want until your disk quota availiable offers

Answer (score 4):

Workspace and project generally refer to the same thing on the Cloud9 website. (source: I work for Cloud9)

Edit: What Hans Zimmermann said is correct and more useful of an answer. A workspace is the virtual machine and you can have as much code and as many projects in there as you like.

You're supposed to have one project per workspace because generally each workspace is setup so it has the correct environment settings / runners for one project.

Comment: Thanks Tim, can I delete a project and use the same workspace to another project?

Comment: @normeno - yep and you can have multiple projects in a workspace. Updated my answer to clarify.